# Hiding a tab in wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

We are using a plugin for portfolio and have added 4 categories to it. Except for the 4 categories, it also shows **All** tab, I would like to hide it.

For that matter, something like this needs to be added as additional JS in header:

```
(function($, undefined) {
  $(function() {
    var cats = $('.sort_by_cat .cat');
    cats.filter(':first').hide();
    cats.filter(':nth(1)').find('a').click();
  });
})(jQuery);
```

here's the [link](http://goldensash.webocity.in/) to the website. I am referring to a portfolio under **Our designers' section**

Now, what classes should I be referring to instead of `.sort_by_cat .cat`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with CSS, simply target the first child using a CSS selector such as nth-child:

```
.portfolio-category-tab-filter li:nth-child(1) {
    display: none;
}
```

Or first-of-type:

```
.portfolio-category-tab-filter li:first-of-type {
    display: none;
}
```

Or first-child:

```
.portfolio-category-tab-filter li:first-child {
    display: none;
}
```

Using CSS means that in the event that the user has JS disabled the element will still be hidden.

If you do however need to use JS then you could use any of the above selectors like so:

```
var element_to_hide = document.querySelector('.portfolio-category-tab-filter li:first-of-type');

element_to_hide.parentNode.removeChild(element_to_hide);
```

or with jQuery you can use [.remove()](https://api.jquery.com/remove/) which takes the element and everything inside it out of the DOM:

```
jQuery('.portfolio-category-tab-filter li:first-of-type').remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use css selector to select that element and remove it from the DOM.

```
(function($, undefined) {
  $(function() {
    var link= $('.portfolio-lists a[data-filter="*"');
    link.remove()
  });
})(jQuery);
```